# Is there a relationship between doing these bit operations on the numbers they produce

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Hey guys I'm a second year uni student and  I'm really new to using bits and bitwise operations. When I got the binary of 3 (0011), and reversed it (1100) and then shifted it right I get (0110) and 6 as the decimal number. If i do this with 2 I get 2. I was wondering if there was some generic relationship to find what n would become doing those 2 operations on it, because I think it might be the key to one of my homework questions.

Also does anyone have a good resource to learn about simple bitwise operations and properties in general for a school kid

Comment: *"and reversed it (1100)"* -- you did your computations on 4 bits; if you represent the numbers on 8 bits you get a different result (`11000000` which is `192`). 8 bits (1 byte) is the regular unit of information in computers these days (in the last 40 years, actually). But you can also represent it on 2, 4 or 8 bytes and your final result will be different in all these situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I got the binary of 3 (0011), and reversed it (1100) and then
>   shifted it right I get (0110) and 6 as the decimal number.

1. You are assuming a 4 bit number, what if there is 16 or 32 bit number system? Your results will change accordingly.
2. Shifting right are two operations, unsigned right shift and signed right shift. Seems like you performed an unsigned right shift since, signed right shift will replace bits according to sign. If it's a negative number (Most significant bit is 1), all replaced bits will be 1, otherwise 0.

> I was wondering if there was some generic relationship to find what n
>   would become doing those 2 operations on it.

Answer to this statement is, it totally varies.

> Also does anyone have a good resource to learn about simple bitwise
>   operations and properties in general for a school kid

I luckily just recently have blogged about [Number System and Bit operations](https://javanotable.blogspot.com/2017/04/bitwise-operations.html).